# Clarity on puppet agent utilization of catalog file at node side

Tags: puppet

I want to know once the catalog is compiled and sent to the agent node, how the agent node uses it. Does it use providers to read the catalog file?

Comment: You should probably read the documentation for the Puppet agent and manifest/catalog located below. It should answer your question. https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/subsystem_catalog_compilation.html

Comment: i have already read that. its explain what happens at server side. i want to know what happens at client side. how my agent use this catalog. does it has some mechanism to do this ???

Answer (score 0):

Puppet is basically using a root shell to interpret system commands that have been compiled from the catalog into the manifest for the system. See the puppet log on the node for what is happening. Additionally, you could run the agent with the `--debug` flag to set up debugging output, like:

```
root-# puppet agent --debug -tv
(lots of output...)
```